# Flutter - Physical keyboard enter key is not working on filed submitted

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, keyboard-events, flutter-dependencies

Here, I am having one add product field and when i submit that field it will add a product but when i am attaching the keyboard and then hit enter it will not submitting that filed instead of that it will go to the new line. can you anyone help me with this? thank you in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

You need help from `textInputAction`

Take a try with this:

```
TextField(
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
      onSubmitted: (value) {
        print("onSubmitted $value");
      },
    );
```